# Error uploading to App Store Connect in Mojave 10.14.1 full version

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-mojave, app-store-connect

I just upgraded to Mojave 10.14.1's full version, and I've been having trouble uploading my app to App Store Connect.

I get the following error, which I have seen on many other SO questions:

`Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 9 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.`

I am using the full version of Xcode (10.1) that released earlier today and the full version of Mojave. How do I get rid of this warning so I can upload to App Store Connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it to work now. I assume something was slow at Apple's end in authenticating Xcode 10.1 and Mojave 10.14.1. I reuploaded the same build I was trying to do yesterday and now it is working.

Comment: Had the same issue last night, but today it is working properly! Thank you

Comment: @Marcianin You're welcome. I assume that this occurs for a few hours every time Apple releases a new version, but this is the first time I have tried to use App Store Connect coincidentally at the same time. Good to know for the future!